# Keeping app specific variables when using continuous integration in IBM Cloud

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have an application written in Node.js that I am deploying to the IBM Cloud infrastructure. Everything works great as long as I have the environment variables for the app embedded in my manifest.yml file. This isn't ideal since it keeps these secure values within my GitHub repository.

I use a .env file for my local testing and placing that in my .gitignore is great to ensure that it doesn't roll out to the Git repo, but having to place the values into my manifest really defeats the purpose.

Is there a way to ensure that my environment variables are kept between CI runs that I store on my IBM Cloud apps without resorting to storing them in the manifest?

Comment: What type of "IBM Cloud infrastructure"? What type of compute environment? Many allow to bind configuration to the app, but each compute environment / standard has its own way. Add more details

Comment: I am using Cloud Foundry instances using Toolchain to perform the deployment. As I stated below, I can use the `cf push "$CF_APP" --no-start` `cf set-env "$CF_APP" dbUrl "${dbUrl}"` calls to do what I want without having it in the manifest, but it just seems a work around rather than how it should be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Cloud Foundry, then I would recommend to take a look at how [Cloud Foundry integrates with services](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/). It allows to bind a service to an app, thereby making the credentials available. If you already have some services, like another database, you can utilize the [concept of user-provided service](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/user-provided.html). There is no need to set variables, it is managed by Cloud Foundry.

Those concepts integrate well with the Continuous Delivery service on IBM Cloud.

Comment: That got me on the right track. I now have the database connected through the manifest, thanks! Now to work on getting my email system linked up too.

Answer (score 0):

where you run continuous integration? if you run on IBM Cloud Continuous Delivery you can set Environment Variable and provide access to your job to access it.

you can see the documentation in [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/ContinuousDelivery?topic=ContinuousDelivery-deliverypipeline_about#environment_properties).

Comment: Yes I'm running on the IBM Cloud CD. Setting the environment variables in there only give access to the variable during the run of the delivery pipeline.

I was able to edit the script and force the deploy of those variables by the following:
`cf push "$CF_APP" --no-start`
`cf set-env "$CF_APP" dbUrl "${dbUrl}"`

Again, it feels like I'm hacking that together instead of creating something that follows the correct design.